# Create contour in opencv.js

Tags: javascript, opencv

I want to convert a list of points to contours (similar to the contours returned by [findContours](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/d0/d43/tutorial_js_table_of_contents_contours.html) in opencv.js).
I'm thinking something like this:

```
let points = [[10,10],[100,10],[100,100],[10,100]]
var contours = new cv.MatVector();
for (var i = 0; i < points.length; ++i) {
   contours.push_back(new cv.Mat(points[i][0], points[i][1]))
}
```

But it is throwing me following error;

> TypeError: right-hand side of 'in' should be an object, got number

Answer (score 0):

Didn't understand what where you trying to do with the contours, but googling similar error brought me here.

`cv.Mat` constractor requires two arguments: the first is `cv.Size` of the mat, and the type of the cells of the resulting Mat(e,g: `cv.CV_8UC1`).

```js
let points = [[10,10],[100,10],[100,100],[10,100]];
var contours = new cv.MatVector();
for (var i = 0; i < points.length; ++i) {
    contours.push_back(new cv.Mat(new cv.Size(points[i][0], points[i][1]), cv.CV_8UC1 ));
}
```

Comment: With `cv.Size` you are assigning the size of the `cv.Mat`. How to initialize `cv.mat` at the same time ?

Comment: What values do you want to initialize your mat to? you can use `cv.Mat.zeros`, `cv.Mat.ones` or `new cv.Mat(other, new cv.Rect(...))`

Comment: Basically I want to initialize a `Mat` or `MatVector` with the points of a polygon.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation on OpenCV.js is very sparse on this, but I did figure out how to do this eventually.

The drawContours function appears to expect a Mat with one row, as many columns as you have points, and two channels of type CV_32S. Besides that the cv.matFromArray function expects a one dimensional array, so you'll need to flatten the array of points.

```
let points = [[10,10],[100,10],[100,100],[10,100]];
let contours = new cv.MatVector();
let mat = cv.matFromArray(1, points.length, cv.CV_32SC2, points.flat(2));
contours.push_back(mat);

// contours can now be used in drawContours(), f.e.:
let noArray = new cv.Mat();
let color = new cv.Scalar(255, 0, 0, 255);
cv.drawContours(image, contours, -1, color, 1, cv.LINE_8);

// cleanup
noArray.delete();
mat.delete();
contours.delete();
```